# Real integral by keyhole contour

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x \; dx}{x^{2} + 2x + 2}$$

by integrating a branch of $(\log z)^{2}/(z^{2} + 2z +2)$ along a keyhole contour.

The thing I have trouble with is why I should be examining the square of the log - I guess it has something to do with ln x in fact NOT being the real part of log z, since log z is (or can be) defined on the entire negative real axis and ln x can't. But looking at the square would definitely not have been my first plan of attack :(

Comment: You may wish to re-evaluate which answer you accepted; the one currently unaccepted is excellent and should serve as a model for other similar computations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are some details of the calculation. Let the keyhole contour be oriented counterclockwise and have the slot on the positive real axis. Call the segment above the real axis $\Gamma_1$, the large circle of radius $R$  $\Gamma_2$, the segement below the real axis $\Gamma_3$ and the circle of radius $\epsilon$ around the origin $\Gamma_4.$  We use the branch of the logarithm with the cut along the positive real axis and returning an argument from zero to $2\pi.$ Note that the poles of $$\frac{1}{z^2+2z+2}$$ are at
$$(z+1)^2 + 1 = 0$$ or
$$\rho_{0,1} = -1 \pm i.$$
Calling the desired integral $I$, we have 
$$\left(\int_{\Gamma_1} + \int_{\Gamma_2} + \int_{\Gamma_3} + \int_{\Gamma_4}\right)
\frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2} dz
\\= 2\pi i 
\left(\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2}; z = -1 + i\right)
+ \mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2}; z = -1 - i\right)\right).$$
Now along the large circle we have
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_2} \frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2} dz\right|
\sim 2\pi R \times \frac{\log^2 R}{R^2} \rightarrow 0$$
as $R\rightarrow\infty.$
Along the small circle we get
$$\left|\int_{\Gamma_4} \frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2} dz\right|
\sim 2\pi \epsilon \frac{\log^2\epsilon}{2} \rightarrow 0$$ 
as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ by repeated application of L'Hôpital's rule.

Now the residues are easy to compute because the poles are simple and we obtain
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2}; z = -1 + i\right)
= \frac{1}{2i} \log^2(-1+i)$$
and $$\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2}; z = -1 - i\right)
= - \frac{1}{2i} \log^2(-1-i)$$
As we actually do the computation of these residues we need to be careful to use the same branch of the logarithm as in the integral. A computer algebra system might use a different branch!

For the first residue we get
$$\frac{1}{2i} \left(\frac{1}{2}\log 2 + \frac{3}{4} i\pi\right)^2
= \frac{1}{2i} 
\left(\frac{1}{4}\log^2 2 - \frac{9}{16} \pi^2 + \frac{3}{4}\log 2 \times i\pi\right)$$ 
and for the second one
$$-\frac{1}{2i} \left(\frac{1}{2}\log{2} + \frac{5}{4} i\pi\right)^2
= -\frac{1}{2i} 
\left(\frac{1}{4}\log^2 2 - \frac{25}{16} \pi^2 + \frac{5}{4}\log 2 \times i\pi\right)$$ 
Adding these contributions yields
$$\frac{1}{2i} \left(\pi^2 - \frac{1}{2}i\pi \log 2\right).$$

Finally we get
$$\left(\int_{\Gamma_1} + \int_{\Gamma_3} \right)
 \frac{\log^2 z}{z^2+2z+2} dz = 2\pi i \times
\frac{1}{2i} \left(\pi^2 - \frac{1}{2}i\pi \log 2\right)
= \pi^3 - \frac{1}{2}i\pi^2 \log 2$$
Observe that along $\Gamma_3$ the logarithm term produces (actually $x$ would be a better choice of variable here rather than $z$)
$$-(\log^2 z + 4\pi i \log z -4\pi^2).$$
The first of these cancels the integral along $\Gamma_1$ and the third is real so that equating imaginary parts we find
$$I = \int_{\Gamma_1}  \frac{\log z}{z^2+2z+2} dz
= - \frac{1}{4\pi} \left(- \frac{1}{2} \pi^2 \log 2\right) = \frac{1}{8} \pi\log 2.$$
We also get the following bonus integral (comparing real parts)
$$ \int_{\Gamma_1}  \frac{1}{z^2+2z+2} dz = \frac{\pi^3}{4\pi^2} = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Nicely done (+1)

Comment: Very kind of you. An upvote from an undisputed wizard. ;-) I actually lost some time on this one before I figured out that Maple uses the branch of the logarithm with the cut on the negative real axis (I believe Mathematica does as well) rather than the positive real axis.

Comment: I upvoted you based on that observation.  It is crucial.  If I have learned anything, and want to impart anything, it is that.  Good work.  Maybe Maple/Mathematica will catch up one day.  Maybe not.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel, you said in the beginning that it goes around $2\pi$ but if the contour is a keyhole then it starts at zero but it doesnt come back to the same point. So it starts ABOVE the axis, but ends BELOW the axis. How is that $= 2\pi$?

Answer (score 3):

This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28V.29_.E2.80.93_the_square_of_the_logarithm) page goes through a very similar example in detail. The reason for the square there is that the $\log(z)^2$'s from two halves of the contour cancel, but they leave behind a cross term that doesn't cancel, which allows you to compute the original integral. I find it rather magical. Put another way, try it without the square and the $\log(z)$'s will cancel, so that's no good.