# How can I prove $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\ln(x)}{(x+a)^2+b^2} dx = \frac{\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}{b} \arctan(\frac{b}{a})$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I consider the following:

$$f(z) = \frac{\operatorname{Ln} (z)}{(z+a)^2+b^2}$$

And the contour:

[image: CONTOUR]

Then, $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z= -a+ib$

But after developing , I didn't get that result. How could I prove it?

Comment: where exactly lies the problem? i guess you have to take care about the argument of your residue..

Comment: @tired I'm not sure , my calculations are correct (I think)... But did not get the result.

Comment: post you solution, then we might me much better able to help you :)

Comment: i also quite sure that there are some constraints on $a$ and $b$ because the result will certainly depends on there sign

Comment: @tired yes, are real numbers.

Comment: I think this question would be better if you showed us what result you got, and your calculations. This way, someone might point out the error you did, and suggest another way to work on it. And you will probably learn from what you did...

Comment: You might want to adapt the solution at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621131/).

Answer (score 0):

You made the mistake of choosing a contour that doesn't end up with your choice of integral. one alternative is choosing the standard keyhole contour with a branch cut from $0 \to \infty$, and restrict $\arg z\in(0,2\pi]$. If $a,b\in\mathfrak{R^{+}}$ now, instead of choosing $\frac{\log(z)}{(z+a)^2+b^2}$, you choose $\frac{\log^{2}(z)}{(z+a)^2+b^2}$, and it will be clear very soon why.

Now by Residue theorem, $$\oint_{C}\frac{\log^{2}(z)}{(z+a)^2+b^2}dz={-4\pi \over b}\left(\ln\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)\cdot i\arctan({b \over a})-\pi \arctan({b \over a})\right)$$

When you open $\log(z)=\log|z|+i \arg(z)$, be careful of the fact that $\arg z\in(0,2\pi]$ so if $\arctan({b \over a})=\theta$, then the argument at residues becomes $\pi \pm \theta$ because $a$ and $b$ are both positive and the residues lie in the second and first quadrant. Then we have

$$\implies {-4\pi \over b}\left(\ln\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)\cdot i \arctan({b \over a})-\pi \arctan({b \over a})\right)$$$$=\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty,\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{\epsilon}^{R}\frac{\log^{2}(z)}{(z+a)^2+b^2}+\int_{R}^{\epsilon}\frac{\left(\log(z)+2\pi i\right)^{2}}{(z+a)^2+b^2}dz$$ and the integrals over outer and inner circles of radius R and $\epsilon$ collapse in the limit. Equate the imaginary and real parts to get $\int_{\mathfrak{R^{+}}}\frac{\log(z)dz}{(z+a)^2+b^2}=\frac{\ln\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)}{b}\arctan({b \over a})$ and $\int_{\mathfrak{R^{+}}}\frac{dx}{(x+a)^2+b^2}=\frac{\arctan({\frac{b}{a}})}{b}$