# Counterfeit proof about $-\frac{3}{2} i \pi\log(2) = \pi^2 - \frac{1}{2} \pi i \log(2)$

Tags: complex-numbers

When I do this [contour integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621131/real-integral-by-keyhole-contour), facing a extreme predicament, I have some difference about the residue part.

Here is my step:

To make it simple, I want to know the extra form of $\log^2 (-1+i)-\log^2 (-1-i)$.

Then it is apparently a form of differences of squares, so I factorize it and get  $$[\log (-1+i)+\log (-1-i) ][\log (-1+i)-\log (-1-i) ] = \log ((-1+i) (-1-i)) \log (\frac{-1+i}{-1-i})  = \log 2 \log -i = -\frac{\pi}{2} log 2$$.

But the correct answer gives:

> $$\log^2 (-1+i) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\log^2 2 - \frac{9}{16} \pi^2 + \frac{3}{4}\log 2 \times i\pi\right)\tag{1}$$
>   and 
>   $$\log^2 (-1-i) =\left(\frac{1}{4}\log^2 2 - \frac{25}{16} \pi^2 + \frac{5}{4}\log 2 \times i\pi\right)\tag{2}$$
>   From $(1)-(2)$,  $\log^2 (-1+i) -\log^2 (-1-i)  = \left(\pi^2 - \frac{1}{2}i\pi \log 2\right)$

I use [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clog%5E2%20(-1%2Bi)-%5Clog%5E2%20(-1-i)) and its result is mine but obviously, mine is not correct because with that I continued my calculation finally got a different answer.

Can someone help me? I really struggle with this different. Any help, I will thank.

Here $log^2(x) \text{ equals } log(x) \times \ log(x)$

Comment: Usually $\log^2(x)$ means $\log(\log(x))$. Do you use a different notation?

Comment: @KennyLau Yes $log^2(x) = log(x) \times \ log(x)$. I think log(log(x)), $log  \circ log(x)$ supposes to be.

Comment: Complex $\log$ is a multi-valued function. If you use another value, you can get $\log^2(-1-i)=\left(\dfrac14\log^22-\dfrac{9}{16}\pi^2-\dfrac34\log2\times i\pi\right)$, which should produce your answer.

Comment: Do you have any idea which branch you should use for your contour integral?

Comment: My answer to$ \log^2 (-1+i)-\log^2 (-1-i)$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2} log 2$

Comment: I know, you don't need to repeat that. I only stated the second term. The first term is the same.

Comment: @KennyLau what is branch? I once heard a term called branch cut. Is that it?

Comment: Do you understand that complex $\log$ is multi-valued? For example, $\log(e^{i\pi})$ can be $i\pi$ or $3i\pi$ or $5i\pi$.

Comment: @KennyLau but the key issue is that I use my difference of square method. It comes up with a different result and wolframalpha approve it.

Comment: I say again. If you use another value of $\log$, you can come up with $\log^2(-1-i)=\left(\dfrac14\log^22-\dfrac{9}{16}\pi^2-\dfrac34\log2\times i\pi\right)$.

Comment: If you use this and $(1)$, you will get your answer.

Comment: @KennyLau Yes of cause otherwise I will not say that $\log -i = \frac{-\pi}{2} $

Comment: So the point is that the "correct answer" used another value of $\log^2(-1-i)$. Do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: But I have a question that since log is multi-valued,  why $\log^2(-1-i)= (\log(2) - 3/4 \pi *i)^2$ rather than $\log^2(-1-i)= (\log(2) - 3/4 \pi *i + 2\pi * i)^2$ ? (here star is multiplication)

Comment: Both should be $\frac34i\pi$ instead of $\frac34\pi$.

Comment: And the reason is that you can only use one value for the contour integral. And I'm asking you which value you should use.

Comment: Which means, more context on the contour integral please. In which step do you encounter this problem?

Comment: @kennyLau When I try to sum the residue of poles.

Comment: Can you show us the integral that generated the poles?

Comment: @kennyLau that's why my first statement there.

Comment: Can you see the sentence "As we actually do the computation of these residues we need to be careful to use the same branch of the logarithm as in the integral." in the answer?

Comment: Can you see the sentence "We use the branch of the logarithm with the cut along the positive real axis and returning an argument from zero to 2π."?

Comment: @kennyLau sorry I have not. Thanks a lot. I finally come up with correct answer with my original method and I have one question: what is branch cut for logarithm function.

Comment: Since $\log$ is multi-valued, we need to use one branch of it, which is another way of saying we need to make it single-valued by choosing one value for every input.

Comment: Yes so $\mathbb R \times \{u| u = ki, 0 \leq k \leq 2 \pi \}$ is a codomain for logarithm function output single value?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @kennyLau it include all the complex number whose imaginary part is within $[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\quad\log^2(-1-i)$

$=[(\log(-1-i))]^2$

$=[(\log(\sqrt2e^{5i\pi/4})]^2$

$=[\frac12\log(2)+5i\pi/4 \ +\ 2ni\pi]^2$

Because complex $\log$ is multi-valued.

If we take $n=0$, we would get $\log^2 (-1-i) =\left(\frac{1}{4}\log^2 2 - \frac{25}{16} \pi^2 + \frac{5}{4}\log 2 \times i\pi\right)$, same as the "correct answer" you referenced.

If we take $n=-1$, we would get $\log^2 (-1-i) =\left(\frac{1}{4}\log^2 2 - \frac{9}{16} \pi^2 - \frac{3}{4}\log 2 \times i\pi\right)$, which would produce your answer.

So, which one should we take?

Notice that in the answer you linked to, it is said that "[w]e use the branch of the logarithm with the cut along the positive real axis and returning an argument from zero to $2π$."

Which means, we should make the complex part of the logarithm between $0$ (inclusive) and $2\pi$ (exclusive).

Which means, we should take $n=0$ instead of $n=-1$.