# Complex integration around a keyhole contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Assume that the only singularities of a function h(z) are finitely many poles that lie away from the origin and the negative real axis.
Show that integration of the function
f(z) = h(z)ln z, with − π < arg(z) ≤ π,
around an appropriate keyhole contour, leads to being able to find the value of the integral of h(-x)dx between 0 and infinity.

I have some idea with how to go about this question, by sketching an appropriate keyhole contour and considering each case separately, but I am unsure on how to start and what to consider for the contour. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason we need to consider a keyhole contour in this case is that the behavior of $\log(z)$ is complicated near $0$ and the negative axis (i.e., it's a branch cut, rather than a pole).

Therefore, trying a contour that looks like this (image obtained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/23972/versions/22/previews/chebfun/examples/complex/html/KeyholeContour.html)) might be a good idea. 
[image]

Remember that this contour is to deal with the $\log(z)$ part. To deal with the poles of $h(z)$, you may need to cut out more poles from this contour. The key idea is to obtain an estimate of the integral on (boundary of this contour)-(the boundary that you need for the integral), and use Residue Theorem.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. May I ask, what do you mean by cutting more poles from the contour?

Comment: @S.k The other poles can be treated in the same manner as general meromorphic functions. For instance, look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621131/real-integral-by-keyhole-contour